# Writing lists to database on python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have 3 lists with data like:

```
frame1 = [{'CAR': 'MAZDA'}, {'CAR': 'Ferrari'}, {'CAR': 'BMW'}]

frame2 = [{'country':'India'}, {'country':'Spain'}, {'country':'Mexico'}]

frame3 = [{'year': '2022'}, {'year': '2021'}, {'year': '2020'}]
```

I want to write lists to a database in the form:

```
    CAR   | country | year
______________________________
1 | MAZDA |  India  | 2022
2 |Ferrari|  Spain  | 2021
3 |  BMW  |  Mexico | 2020
```

Comment: OK, and what have you tried?  This is not difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems too vague (*at least for me*).
But as a starting point, with [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)/[`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) :

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

with sqlite3.connect("foo.db") as conn:
    (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(fr) for fr in [frame1, frame2, frame3]], axis=1)
         .to_sql("table", conn, if_exists="fail", index=False)) #adjust the params here
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to somehow combine the same rows into 1 row in the resulting database?

Comment: Yes, can you update your example or open a new question ?

Comment: I open new question

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip()` to loop over the lists in parallel. Then combine the dictionary elements into a tuple, and use `executemany()` to insert all of them into the table.

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO tableName (car, country, year) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'
cursor.executemany(sql, 
    ((v1['CAR'], v2['country'], v3['year']) 
     for v1, v2, v3 in zip(frame1, frame2, frame3))
)
```